# Links to social media on Weblog WP theme

Tags: html, wordpress

I modify a WP theme (Weblog, from ThemeBeans) for a friend, and I have a problem : I got links to social media in the footer of the page, I modified them with theme options, but no matter what, the links are "corrupted".

I mean, when i put in the theme option for twitter account : myUsername, the link goes to  `twitter.com/myUsername%E2%80%8E`, which is a 404 (or kinda).

I checked with Chrome inspector, the link is ok. The source is ok too, no spaces or hidden characters.

I checked by outputing the option with `<span><?php do_action('bean_profile_twitter');?></span>` (this is the way the theme output the value), there's no spaces, hidden character or something else, just the username.

The stranger thing is : when I run my local copy, there's no problem.

See it online, in the footer (check Twitter link) : http://www.enguerranweiss.fr/lab/op2014/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something to do with your link, if you try disabling javascript, when you hover the link it displays as http://www.twitter.com/olivierpineda%E2%80%8E and when I edit the html using firebug, this is what is showing:

```
<a class="social-icon twitter" title="Twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/olivierpineda&lrm;"></a>
```

So, it's either there is something on the input you saved on the theme options, the way you output it in PHP, or a JS meddling with that specific link.

** Hint: you can disable js using the [web developer plugin](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) so you don't have to disable it on the browser directly..

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but I re-typed the username in the field, and it's ok. Even if there was nothing I could see in there (I pressed delete 10 times after the username, selected it to see if there was some spaces...)... Anymay, thank you !

Comment: maybe when you dumped the data into production.. so it's an encoding related issue.. which was inserted back to your live site as a theme option.